# Is it possible to have Celery run an infinite loop in the background? (flask)

Tags: python, celery

I have the following celery task:

```
@celery.task
def ScrapeWhileTrue():
    current_titles = scrape_title()
    current_urls = scrape_url()
    while(True):
        time.sleep(10)
        print("completing a test")
        current_titles2 = scrape_title()
        current_urls2 = scrape_url()
        if current_titles != current_titles2:
            print("New listings!")
            new_titles = set(current_titles2) - set(current_titles)
            new_urls = set(current_urls2) - set(current_urls)
            # send_mail(new_titles, new_urls)
            current_titles = current_titles2
            current_urls = current_urls2
```

Mt HTML contains two buttons, one which sends the data from the form to a different function. The second button I would like to be toggle-able. While its toggled, I would like it to run the above Celery task.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    if request.form['submit'] == 'Send':
        #Set info
        global url
        url = CraiglistScraper(location, postal, max_price, radius, query, carorpart)
        flash('Info set')

    else:
        flash('Scraping')
        ScrapeWhileTrue()


    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Is it possible to have something like this happen? Or would I need to run it as a Daemon (I have no idea how)?

Thanks!

Comment: if you are using celery then don't need to add infinite loop in function . you can use celery schedular to call function in every second which do same thing.